# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the error below error when I try to run my selenium project.

Here is the code:

```
package automationFramework;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class FirstTestCase {

//private static final String JavascriptExecutor = null;


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Launch the Test A Environment
        driver.get("https://ivv-a.entityhub.clarientglobal.dev");


        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Thread.sleep(3000);        
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#username")).sendKeys("user3@imb.com");
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#password")).sendKeys("Cred123#");
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#submit")).click();
        //Thread.sleep(1000);


        //Wait for 15 Sec for the page to load
        Thread.sleep(15000);

        /*Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/nav/div[2]/section/aside/ul/li[2]/a"));
        action.moveToElement(el).build().perform();
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.sticky__body > div.credHeader.ng-scope > nav > div.header__nav--primary.ng-scope > section > aside > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a"))).click().build().perform(); */

        WebElement entityrecordsmenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.sticky__body > div.credHeader.ng-scope > nav > div.header__nav--primary.ng-scope > section > aside > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(entityrecordsmenu).build().perform();

        //provide wait here to display drop-down
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //some time implicitly wait may fails then use thread.sleep
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        WebElement createnewrecord = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.sticky__body > div.credHeader.ng-scope > nav > div.header__nav--primary.ng-scope > section > aside > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a"));
        createnewrecord.click();

        //By locator = By.id("elem2");
        //WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.sticky__body > div.credHeader.ng-scope > nav > div.header__nav--primary.ng-scope > section > aside > ul > li.ng-isolate-scope.selected > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a"));
        //element.click(); 

        //Mouse hover and drop down clicked

        Thread.sleep(13000);



        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-results']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(7000);
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#legalName")).sendKeys("IMB");

        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        WebElement SaveDraftbutton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#submitBtn > span:nth-child(2)"));
        SaveDraftbutton.click();

        Thread.sleep(6000);

        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,900)");

        Thread.sleep(6000);


        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#collapseDocuments > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div.controls.control-group > div.col-md-2.add-doc-button.button.ng-isolate-scope")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\siva.247588\\Desktop\\Clarient+AML+Questionnaire.docx");

    }

}
```

I have added some parts of the code. This was working fine earlier. I unfortunately made some changes in the path of the jar files after which its showing the below error message.

```
Exception in thread main"org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
    Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
    System info: host: 'CHNMCT271738D', ip: '10.87.32.163', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
    Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver"
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Could you share the code you're using to start the session?

Comment: Hi, Please check the edit and advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can't straight away start the chrome browser like this

> WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

First down load the chrome driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

Then set system property

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path to download chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Then chrome browser will be opened without any issues.

Comment: This is only true if the chromedriver.exe is not set in the PATH.

Comment: But why was it working fine earlier? I never used System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path to download chromedriver.exe"); and always used WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); and it was working fine earlier before i made changes to my eclipse project

Comment: I  have already set the chromedriver.exe in the same folder to that of eclipse.. So i am guessing it shouldnt be the issue

Comment: may be but try once with System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path to download chromedriver.exe"); let see

Comment: Yes.. I tried.. I got the below error:  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'CHNMCT271738D', ip: '10.87.32.163', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Comment: I tried the command WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome()); and it launched the chrome browser without any issues.. Why is this?

Comment: great..be happy :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the command WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome()); and it launched the chrome browser without any issues..